# install war file at server deploy directory

Tags: maven-2, jboss, jboss5.x

I'm want to have the war file deployed in the server deploy directory (or any directory of my choice) along with the one deployed in the repository. Also, can I control the name of the war file deployed like, I don't want the war file to be projectname-1.0.war I just want the name of the war file be projectname.war.

Thanks,

Ravi

Answer (score 8):

Thanks guys,

I got it working. here is what I did.

I added this in my pom.xml file

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warName>mavenproject1</warName>
            <outputDirectory>C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

This solved both my naming and placing the war file.

Ravi

Answer (score 3):

A first option would be to use the [JBoss Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/index.html) that allows to start/stop JBoss and deploy/undeploy applications via JMX.

Your configuration must set the location to your JBoss Home directory. This can be done by setting the home directory with the `jbossHome` tag in the plugin configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <jbossHome>C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA</jbossHome>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then, just use one of the goal defined [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), like:

```
$ mvn jboss:deploy
```

---

Another option would be to use the [Cargo Maven Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin). Below an example of plugin configuration that you could add to your war project:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <wait>false</wait>
    <container>
      <containerId>jboss5x</containerId>
      <home>C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA</home>
    </container>

    <configuration>
      <type>existing</type>
      <properties>
        ...
      </properties>
    </configuration>
  </configuration>
<plugin>
```

Then, to deploy a "[deployable](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deployable)" (here, your war) to a running container:

```
$ mvn cargo:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

'Deployment' may sound very technical but its just copying file to the deployment directory. In some cases you may have to restart the server.

Comment: right now I'm copying the war file from my repository to the deploy dir (after the build). I don't want to repeat this task again and again. When I do the build, a copy of the newly created war file is copied in the server deploy dir.

Answer (score 1):

To change what it deploys the file as, use the  tag in the build section of your pom.xml to specify the package name.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/sign-mojo.html